# Robust source search for Tex-sourcecode

Tags: sourcecode

We use latex in the backend of a web application which stores exercises.
To make exercises easier to find, we thought about implementing a source-code search.

But we stumbled upon a lot of problems because there are many ways to typeset the exact same math-formular:

```
x_i^2
x^2_i
x_{i}^2
...
```

Is there any way to transform tex code in a robust way into a plain string?
Or can something like this be extracted from a pdf or dvi file?
Or maybe even generated while compiling the document?

Comment: If you really want to do some serious log file mining, sticking ```\tracingall``` in your .tex file gives identical output for all of the above in the .log file, but it will be messy to work with!

Comment: Adding structured comments could help with future searches (like `%---Exercise:start.` etc). Makes regex possible.